# ffmpeg "-bug" parameter explanation

Tags: ffmpeg

I found "-bug" parameter for **ffmpeg** in one of encoding scripts, and have no idea what it is. **ffmpeg** man page says that it's action for not autodetected encoder bugs, but I can't find any information what values can I pass to this option.

Does anybody know anything about "-bug" **ffmpeg** parameter?

Comment: Where did you find this, exactly? My man page of a fairly recent ffmpeg doesn't mention it.

Comment: Found it in some red hat man page (don't remember link now). Question is solved - recent ffmpeg documentation provide enough info about this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found good description in recent [**ffmpeg** documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html):

**bug** flags (decoding,video)
Workaround not auto detected encoder bugs.
Possible values:

- autodetect
- old_msmpeg4 - some old lavc generated msmpeg4v3 files (no autodetection)
- xvid_ilace - Xvid interlacing bug (autodetected if fourcc==XVIX)
- ump4 - (autodetected if fourcc==UMP4)
- no_padding - padding bug (autodetected)
- amv
- ac_vlc - illegal vlc bug (autodetected per fourcc)
- qpel_chroma
- std_qpel - old standard qpel (autodetected per fourcc/version)
- qpel_chroma2
- direct_blocksize - direct-qpel-blocksize bug (autodetected per fourcc/version)
- edge - edge padding bug (autodetected per fourcc/version)
- hpel_chroma
- dc_clip
- ms - Workaround various bugs in microsoft broken decoders.
- trunc - truncated frames

Comment: I've never used any of these.